# How to add WebRTC ICE Candidate?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm writing a custom application server to control Kurento Media Server.

When I'm trying to add IceCandidate using :

```
webRtcPeer.addIceCandidate
```

I'm getting the error :

```
Failed to construct 'RTCIceCandidate': cannot convert to dictionary. 
at WebRtcPeerSendrecv.WebRtcPeer.addIceCandidate (kurento-utils.min.js:2)
```

Here are some candidates that need to be added to webrtc :

```
candidate:1 1 UDP 2015363327 172.31.46.122 11836 typ host
candidate:2 1 TCP 1015021823 172.31.46.122 9 typ host tcptype active
candidate:3 1 TCP 1010827519 172.31.46.122 2089 typ host tcptype passive
candidate:4 1 UDP 2015363583 fe80::c08:83ff:feef:264c 7391 typ host
candidate:5 1 TCP 1015022079 fe80::c08:83ff:feef:264c 9 typ host tcptype active
```

Can anyone help please with this error ?

Thanks
cheers,

Comment: What exactly are you inputting into ```addIceCandidate```? Just the string after 'candidate:'?

Comment: @Inogueir I'm putting the entire row : [candidate:1 1 UDP 2015363327 172.31.46.122 11836 typ host]

Comment: You most likely have to provide ```sdpMLineIndex``` and ```sdpMid``` information. I thought you were having issues adding candidates from a kurento peer in the browser. But looks like your issue is adding the candidate in kurento. I will have to look at their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Kurento Client Docs](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/client-javadoc/org/kurento/client/WebRtcEndpoint.html), the input to `addIceCandidate` have to be an [IceCandidate](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/client-javadoc/org/kurento/client/IceCandidate.html).
Based on your description, you are only setting the `candidate` property of the object. You also need `sdpMid` and `sdpMLineIndex` to be successful.

So you should something like this:

```java
IceCandidate incomingCandidate = new IceCandidate(candidate, sdpMid, sdpMLineIndex);

webRtcPeer.addIceCandidate(incomingCandidate);
```

You should be getting the information for `sdpMLineIndex` as well as `sdpMid` from your signalling server along with the candidate string that you already have (aka `candidate:1 1 UDP 2015363327 172.31.46.122 11836 typ host`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with entire info about the candidate but still getting the same error :/ Example of candidate I'm sending : {"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 2015363327 172.31.46.122 57819 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"1"}

Comment: Are you creating the IceCandidate object? Do you mind sharing more of your code than just ```webRtcPeer.addIceCandidate```? So I can take a look more into it.

Comment: I'm not creating it manually. I'm sending it as I get it frrom Kurento Server. As per the documentation (screenshot : https://ibb.co/svL5VCr) Source : https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.11.0/tutorials/node/tutorial-helloworld.html

Comment: My client side code is the same as HelloWorld example here : https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/blob/master/kurento-hello-world/static/js/index.js    I'm getting the error on line 55 in the function ws.onmessage = function(message) {... case 'iceCandidate': webRtcPeer.addIceCandidate(parsedMessage.candidate)}